# Action is pulling the wrong Ruby version

Tags: github, github-actions

I have the following action on my project:

```yaml
jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        gemfile:
          - Gemfile
          - gemfiles/Gemfile-rails-5-2
          - gemfiles/Gemfile-rails-6-0
          - gemfiles/Gemfile-rails-6-1
          - gemfiles/Gemfile-rails-7-0
        ruby:
          - 2.6
          - 2.7
          - 3.0
          - 3.1
        exclude:
          - ruby: 2.6
            gemfile: Gemfile
          - ruby: 2.6
            gemfile: gemfiles/Gemfile-rails-7-0
          - ruby: 3.0
            gemfile: gemfiles/Gemfile-rails-5-0
          - ruby: 3.1
            gemfile: gemfiles/Gemfile-rails-5-0
          - ruby: 3.0
            gemfile: gemfiles/Gemfile-rails-5-1
          - ruby: 3.1
            gemfile: gemfiles/Gemfile-rails-5-1
          - ruby: 3.0
            gemfile: gemfiles/Gemfile-rails-5-2
          - ruby: 3.1
            gemfile: gemfiles/Gemfile-rails-5-2
```

as stated, I have Ruby versions 3.0 and 3.1.

Now I noticed the weirdest thing: Tests for Ruby 3.0 are using 3.1, as the [output shows](https://github.com/luizkowalski/concurrent_rails/runs/4780570655?check_suite_focus=true).

I assume it has something to do with the fact that the Ruby versions are not quoted. To test that assumption, [I quoted all the Ruby versions](https://github.com/luizkowalski/concurrent_rails/runs/4780600693?check_suite_focus=true) and now the tests are using the right version. This actually fixed the problem but it left me scratching my head:

First, the VSCode linter complains about the file:

[image]

but I don't see any problems on GitHub.

Second, I noticed that other gems like [Devise](https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/main/.github/workflows/test.yml) don't use quoted Ruby versions and its tests are just fine, using the right Ruby version...

So what is going on?

I noticed that for previous actions, before I quoted the versions, this is what Github was showing:

[image]

as one can see, it shows `3` instead of `3.0` and I suspect that this is why Ruby was evaluating to 3.1 instead of 3.0.

Comment: hi, some hints to improve your question and make it more likely to get an answer: please try and make the example as small as possible to show the problem. please don't include screenshots with errors etc. screenshots are not searchable for people with the same problem in the future :)

Comment: thanks for the tips but there are links to the actual actions, outputs, and PR